# How to include library with meson?

Tags: c, compilation, meson-build

I want to add the [INHI library](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih) (which use meson too) to my project but I don't know how to.

The project tree :

```
Project/
- meson.build
- src/
- - meson.build
- - inih/
- - main.c
```

The root meson.build contains :

```
project('test', 'c')
subdir('src')
```

src/meson.build

```
executable('main', 'main.c')
```

What do I have to add in the meson.build for using inih in main.c ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meson has a concept of `subprojects`.

1. Create a `subprojects` directory on the top level of your project (The same level where you have `meson.build`).
2. Create a `wrap` file for your `dependency` inside the `subprojects` directory and name it `inih.wrap` with content:

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://github.com/benhoyt/inih
revision = head
```

this tells meson to use `git` to get a `dependency`.

3. In your `meson.build` integrate `inih` as `dependency` like this:

```
inih_sp = subproject('inih')
inih_dep = inih_sp.get_variable('inih_dep')
...
executable('main', 'main.c',dependencies:[inih_dep])
```

EDIT:
The other way is to use `wrap-file` instead of `wrap-git`. In this case, only the second item would change. Simply find your library [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrapdb-projects.html) and put it in the `subprojects` directory.

For more information, check [Wrap dependency system manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html)